# Unable to restart SSH daemon: Missing init script

Tags: ssh, init.d

When I try to restart the ssh server I get the following output:

```
bash: /etc/init.d/ssh: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Is openssh-server installed? Please add the output of `dpkg -s openssh-server`

Answer (score 3):

The script is named /etc/init.d/sshd  not ssh.